# undefined method `where` for searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I'm trying to add a date range filter to my searchkick

This is what i have

```
    @events = Event.page(params[:page]).per(10).search(params[:search], misspellings: { distance: 1 }, order: { date: :asc, eventname: :asc }, match: :word_start, page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    if params[:date_from]
      byebug
@events = @events.where('date BETWEEN ? AND ?', params[:date_from], params[:date_to])
    end
```

However the issue i'm getting is this:

```
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `where' for #<Searchkick::Results:0x007f95eaf97f90>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Edit**

I know this is potentially better in another question but its kinda the same question

```
 def search
    @events = Event.page(params[:page]).per(10)
    if params[:date_from]
        @events = @events.where('date between ? AND ?', params[:date_from], params[:date_to])
    byebug
    end

    @events = @events.search(params[:search], misspellings: { distance: 1 }, order: { date: :asc, eventname: :asc }, match: :word_start, page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    if @events.results.any?
      render 'events/results'
    end
end
```

Now this isn't working how i want it, I've got the event name, the datefrom and to being passed through on the params. If i type `@events` on the byebug it gets events in the range, but doesnt get the event i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like searchkick uses it's own query syntax. so something like this might help

```
search_opts = {
  misspellings: { distance: 1 }, 
  order: { date: :asc, eventname: :asc },
  match: :word_start, 
  page: params[:page],
  per_page: 20
}
if params[:date_from]
   search_opts[:where] =  { date: {gte: params[:date_from], lte: params[:date_to]} }
end

@events = Event.search params[:search], search_opts
```

Comment: Hi there, This shows it however there is an issue, For some reason my date range filter isnt actually working, I'll share my controller now

Comment: doesn't get the event you need? does the event you need live on the start/end date in your between?

Comment: the event does yes, It actually still returns all the events.

Comment: actually in looking, it appears searchkick is doing it's own queries,..  so you will need to add  everything to the searchkick call, and forgo using ActiveRecord query syntax...(Sorry I don't know searchkick was just pointing out the reason for the where not working was not being an ActiveRelation).  what does your params[:search] look like.  you can probably merge the required fields into that.

Comment: The params[:search] just contains the value of what the user puts in. e.g. "Renault"

Comment: see my latest edit, trying to build using searchkick query syntax

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a need to call .page() before .where()
Shouldnt it be

```
def search
  events = Event
  if params[:date_from]
    events = events.where('date between ? AND ?', params[:date_from], params[:date_to])
  end

  events = events.page(params[:page]).per(10)
  @events = events.search(params[:search], misspellings: { distance: 1 }, order: { date: :asc, eventname: :asc }, match: :word_start, page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
  if @events.results.any?
    render 'events/results'
  end
end
```

Comment: So i tried your method, I got this error `undefined method `page' for #<Searchkick::Results:0x007f95e1cbede0>`

Comment: okie, so what is this search method? Also i have changes the code to perform .page on events activerecord result, before search

Comment: the same reason the where doesn't work when changed to search is the same reason that .page won't   the searchkick method is returing a result not an activerelation